# Am I missing an if statement?

Tags: c#, winforms

thanks in advance for any help!

A bit of background basically I am building an application that stores vehicles (cars,truck,buses), I have a vehicle superclass and all the individual classes (car.cs, truck.cs, minibus.cs) inherit from this super class.

I also have a class called 'fleet' that I would like to add the vehicles to an then display the results in a list box.

I have everything else working but I cannot get the trucks and minibus's to update and display on the list box like the cars do.

Here is my fleet class which includes the car.cs; and it works fine and the data taken from the car form gets added and displayed in the listbox.

```
class Fleet
{
    private List<Vehicle> theFleet = new List<Vehicle>(); 

    public List<Vehicle> fleet 
    {
        get
        {
            return theFleet;
        }
    }

    public void deleteFromFleet(Vehicle aCar)
    {
        theFleet.Remove(aCar);
    }

    public void addToFleet(Vehicle aCar)
    {
        theFleet.Add(aCar);
    }
}
```

Here is my main form, that has the list box on it:

```
public partial class FrmHireCo : Form
{
    private Fleet myFleet = new Fleet();
    private ClientList mycustomer = new ClientList();

    //Fleet object used to store cars

    public FrmHireCo()
    {
        //Default constructor
        InitializeComponent();                
    }        

    private void updateFleetList()
    {   
        lstFleet.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Car c in myFleet.fleet)
        {
            string line = "Car: " + c.make+" " + c.colour;
            lstFleet.Items.Add(line);
        }
    }

    private void updateClientList()
    {   
        customers.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Customer c in mycustomer.clientlist)
        {
            string line = "Customer: " + c.name + " " + c.address;
            customers.Items.Add(line);
        }
    }

    private void btnAddCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Add a new car
        FrmCar carGui = new FrmCar(); //Form used to add new car
        carGui.ShowDialog();
        Car myCar = carGui.car;         //Get new car from form
        myFleet.addToFleet(myCar);      //Add to fleet list
        updateFleetList();              //Uodate fleet list
    }

    private void lstFleet_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lstFleet.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            int index = lstFleet.SelectedIndex;
            Car myCar = myFleet.fleet.ElementAt(index);
            FrmCar carGui = new FrmCar();
            carGui.car = myCar;
            carGui.Show();
        }
    }

    private void btnCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FrmCustomer customerGui = new FrmCustomer();
        customerGui.ShowDialog();
        Customer mycustomer = customerGui.customer;         
        mycustomer.addToClientList(mycustomer);      
        updateFleetList();
    }

    private void customers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (customers.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            int index = customers.SelectedIndex;
            Customer myCustomer = mycustomer.clientlist.ElementAt(index);
            FrmCustomer customerGui = new FrmCustomer();
            customerGui.customer = myCustomer;
            customerGui.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers for any help!

Comment: You said the code you provided works.  Can you provide the code that doesn't work as well? That is what you want help with right?

Comment: The only typecasting I see is for Car. I'm not sure where your references to buses and minivans are...  Also I would recommend using a List<interface> rather than List<base class>. This way you won't need to typecast the list contents. Make sure to state the interface contract cleanly so that all the shared properties and functions between cars, buses and minivans are stated in the interface.

Comment: Nothing in the code that you posted actually adds either trucks or minibuses to the listbox. All you're working with are `Car` objects.

Comment: Also, should *foreach (Car c in myFleet.fleet)* not be *foreach (Vehicle c in myFleet.fleet)*

Answer (score 1):

```
private void updateFleetList()
    {   
        lstFleet.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Vehicle c in myFleet.fleet)
        {
            string line = "Car: " + c.make+" " + c.colour;
            lstFleet.Items.Add(line);
        }
    }
```

Comment: foreach should get each vehicle (instead of car) out of the fleet.

Comment: so changing 'Car' to 'Vehicle' in the foreach statement, will allow me to add trucks, minibuses, customers to the list?

Comment: 'private void 1stFleet_SelectedIndexChanged' do I need to add and else statement underneath the if, so that it cant create either car,truck,bus?

Comment: @ryan betts: Just for clarification, changing the `Car` type to `Vehicle` will *not* allow you to add *customers* to the list. Remember as you said in the original question, all of the subtypes of vehicles (cars, trucks, minibuses) inherit from the superclass `Vehicle`. Customers are not a type of vehicle. But it will allow you to add any type that inherits from the `Vehicle` base class.

Comment: @ryan betts: If you want your `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler to show separate forms for each type of vehicle, you need to add an `if` statement that checks the type of each `Vehicle` object as you extract it from the list, and shows the appropriate form. Extract a `Vehicle` object from the list (because everything is a vehicle), and then narrow down with an `if` statement using `typeof` the specific type of vehicle that each one is.

Comment: Vehicle myCar = myFleet.fleet.ElementAt(index);

Comment: I agree with Cody Gray. If you have separate forms for each type, you need to deal with it using if statement. However you can implement your GUI similar to the way you implement your Vehicle: car, truck, minivan, etc., you may be able to avoid using if statement.

Comment: Ye I maybe never explained very well, I have a form for each type of vehicle and I click a button on my main form which loads the individual for I then enter details about it, then I would like it to add the vehicle to the list box on the main page when I click the close button. Sorry if I am being vage, I am still new to programming in regards to experience!

Answer (score 1):

You should include all vehicles.

```
private void updateFleetList()
{   
    lstFleet.Items.Clear();
    foreach (Vehicle v in myFleet.fleet)
    {
        lstFleet.Items.Add(v);  
    }
}
```

Also, just override `ToString` in all your Vehicle subclasses and the `ListBox` will use that inherently; this way not every `Vehicle` needs a `Make` or `Color` property.

Comment: Am I not missing a part of the method to control the list box? Am I missing an if-else statement?

Comment: @ryan betts:  What do you mean by *control the list box*?

Comment: I posted a comment about does this help?

Comment: @ryan betts:  As long as every method that edits Vehicles also edits `myFleet.fleet`, this version of `updateFleetList` does not need to change.

Comment: So if all my classes inherite from vehicle, and I change the updatefleet() code as above it should let me add trucks, minibuses to the fleet, is there anything i need to change in the 'fleet' class, possibly change from 'acar' to 'avehicle'?

Comment: You should do that anyway because they aren't `Cars` but `Vehicles`.